# Is this code thread-safe - Singleton Implementation using Concurrent Dictionary

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

```
class Connection 
{
    private string param1;
    private string param2;
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Connection> 
        connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Connection>();
    private Connection()
    {
    //Prevent instantiation
    }

    private Connection(string param1, string param2)
    {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public static Connection getInstance(string param1, string param2)
    { 
        Connection conn = activeConnections.GetOrAdd(new Tuple<string, string> 
            param1,param2), new Connection (param1, param2));
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that if two threads ask for a connection with the same parameters, they should get the same `Connection`? That means the actual code of `Connection` (the one that uses the parameters and that you didn't show) has to be thread-safe too.

Comment: Also, it's okay to create duplicate `Connection` objects as long as nobody ever sees them, right? (Because that's what you do.)

Comment: @svick 
Ok so here is what I intended to do:
1. If two threads ask for a connection with the same parameters, only one connection object has to be created & used by them.
2. Never create two connection objects with the same parameters. If one exists, use it. Else create a new one.
Is this what I am doing or not?
If this is a bad idea, do elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Never create two connection objects with the same parameters. If one exists, use it.

If you really need to guarantee this, then I think you will need to use locking instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`.

If it's okay to create duplicate `Connection`s (that will never be used) in rare circumstances, then you can use an overload of `GetOrAdd()` that takes a lambda that creates the `Connection`:

```
return activeConnections.GetOrAdd(
    Tuple.Create(param1,param2), _ => new Connection (param1, param2));
```

With your current code, every time you call `getInstance()`, a new `Connection` is created and then most of the time thrown away.

Comment: Ok, I checked if that happens in a crude way, I used a class member - Guid which instantiated every time I created a class.
When I created two objects with same params, the Guids were the same >> SO I assumed they were referencing the same (single) object.
If 2 objects are being created, then they must have different GUID right?
Can you explain that?

Comment: @rtindru Two objects are being *created*, but both calls to `GetOrAdd()` will *return* the same object. Basically, call 2 creates new `Connection`, realizes the dictionary already contains one, so it throws the one it created away and returns the one from the dictionary.

Comment: Oh, that seems like a waste of time and effort. Are you sure about this?
THis is what the msdn website says: 
Adds a key/value pair to the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,Value>` if the key does not already exist.
[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676.aspx

Comment: @rtindru `ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't change how C# works. And method parameters are always evaluated before the method is invoked.

Comment: hmm... Alright, then what is the alternative that you suggest. Because clearly this is a vain effort.

Comment: @rtindru First, it may sound like a waste, but creating a small object for a very short time should have really negligible performance penalty. If you're okay with creating a duplicate in rare cases, use the delegate overload of `GetOrAdd()` I suggested. If you need to ensure there are no duplicates ever, use normal `Dictionary` and locking.

Comment: @svick shouldn't the 2nd argument be: `_ => new Connection (param1, param2)` instead? Actually, I am not sure if it should be `x => new Connection (x.Item1, x.Item2)` hence no closure is needed

Comment: @svick And if possible, could you please elaborate a little more on your first "locking" version in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358761/how-to-improve-this-objects-dictionary-caching-lock-in-multi-thread please

Comment: @colinfang You're right, thanks, fixed. And avoiding that closure would make the code less readable, so I would use the more readable version by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on V4 or later, `Lazy<T>` might help:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Lazy<Connection>> 
    connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Lazy<Connection>>();

public static Connection getInstance(string param1, string param2)
{ 
    var connLazy = activeConnections.GetOrAdd(
        Tuple.Create(param1,param2), 
        new Lazy<Connection>(
            () => new Connection (param1, param2),
            LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
        );
    return conn.Value;
}
```

`GetOrAdd` ensures that every threads will get same object, and extra `Lazy<Connection>` will be discarded. `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication` mode ensures that the instance will be initiated only once and no more.

Answer (score 1):

yes. But it's ugly. You won't remember what those parameters means when you come back in a couple of months and have to maintain the code.

I really hate convenience classes like `Tuple` and `Action<T>` (the latter is OK some times but is usually abused).

It's much better to create small classes which actually describes what the values represent.

Comment: Ok so create a class called ParamDetails with the values and use that as the Key?
Keys do not have to be primitive datatypes?

Comment: `Tuple` is not a primitive either. But you have to implement `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: In this specific case, I disagree. I think `Tuple` as an implementation detail is okay, when it's clear from the surrounding code that `Item1` and `Item2` actually mean `param1` and `param2` (assuming those actually have meaningful names in real code).